Can Triacs work under excessive heat?
I am aiming to design a UPS, however I will design the control board and get an external 2500 VA inverter and switch ON and OFF both of them using Triacs depends on the state of power if it was coming from mains or not. The peak power of the device is rated at 1500 VA, however the problem is:
Each part would be controlled by 2 Triacs (the mains would be controlled by 2 Triacs and the inverter would be controlled by 2 Triacs, so every time only 2 Triacs will work and the other 2 are turned Off), the problem present here is the sever power loss, the Triacs of each part will dissipate 21.7 W of heat (10.85 W each triac) at 7 A 220 VAC, so could this solution work or is it an over kill?
The circuit:
The circuit is not precise but it demonstrates the idea because even the Triac's terminals are inverted
not sure if my calculations are right but in an ambient of 50 C and junction Temp of 100 C and junction to case is 2.3 C/W so I still need a heatsink of around 0.1 C/W for both Triacs of each part, so is it correct!?

What does the datasheet about junction temperature ratings?

as I had seen, 2.3 C/W

@Colin the 2.3 C/W rating is for the insulated Triac, there is another one which is not insulated have 1.4 C/W but what I am testing now is the insulated Triac

Why is your ambient spec 50'C? do you have forced air over heatsink?

I’d be using a relay for safety. Triacs leak so your incoming ac plug will have voltage on it. Using a 12A triac for a 10A load is asking for failure.

Can the inverter not be wired common-neutral with the mains? Is it not isolated? -- is isolation required to be provided by such a changeover switch? TRIACs are explicitly NOT isolation!

@D.A.S. no but the air temperature of the place can reach 50 C

@Kartman Peak current is 7A

@TimWilliams, the inverter can't be connected to common-neutral with the mains because if the mains plug connected in reverse; live and neutral got reversed, then  surely a disaster will occur. Isolation is not required after all both of them are 220 VAC so not really important. of course there will be leakage current but it is negligible.

@D.A.S. I'm not quite familiar with thermal topics unfortunately so I don't know which fan would be suitable for such application so for now just used a normal heatsink and thought of testing it with a fan in the design level.

If the inverter is otherwise insulated, how would it know which one is which (H/N)?

@TimWilliams the output of the inverter won't be insulated at the output so the inverter is like a live wire as I had measured it

@HazardousVoltage  look at a GPU card and cool it like that.

Triacs are wrong parts for this. You’ll want IGBTs or mosfets, and the AC input needs to be isolated with a relay as well, so that the inverter output doesn’t back-feed onto the AC plug.
The inverter should be synchronized to mains when mains is available. That way the switchover will be smooth. So you can’t really use a typical inverter as they don’t have a sync input. You need to design your own or find an inverter with a sync input.

Could you explain the differences between TRIACs, IGBTs and MOSFETs here? The distinction seems arbitrary (e.g. both TRIACs and IGBTs have a diode-like voltage drop).

The inverter will not back-feed onto the AC plug because it will be blocked by the Triac (of course not isolated but blocked) I tried it with a small load of 20W LED light bulb and it worked fine, but have no idea about the sync, because all would controlled via an MCU.

Would be thankful if you could do as Mr.@TimWilliams asked, or if you have a document explaining using the other alternatives in such application
